# Kindle Fire: PopupMenu$OrientationChangeListener leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, kindle-fire

I have a little popup menu that anchors on a button in the action bar. This works well on 3.0/3.1 Xoom and Galaxy tabs, and a 4.1 Nexus 7.

However, on a 7" Fire HD ([this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0083PWAPW)), I get an error about a leaked intent receiver when exiting the application. The error occurs only if the menu was not opened during that run.

There is no mention of `OrientationChangeListener` in [the one copy of the source I've found](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-platform-apps/Gallery3D/com/cooliris/media/PopupMenu.java.htm); I suspect Amazon has a different implementation.

**Questions**:

- Has anyone encountered this?
- Does anyone know of a workaround or a fix?
- (Where) can I find Amazon's source code?
- Finally, (*shudder*) how important is it that I don't leak a receiver on application exit?

Here is the menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_profile"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_profile" 
        ></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_logout"
        ></item>

</menu>
```

This is where I register it:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    MenuItem login = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_login);
    Button button = (Button) login.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.login);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            profileMenu.show();
        }
    });


    // profileMenu is an instance field
    profileMenu = new PopupMenu(this, button);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile_menu, profileMenu.getMenu());
    profileMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // there was code here, but I removed it all and the problem persists
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526): Activity **.app.ListActivity has leaked IntentReceiver android.widget.PopupMenu$OrientationChangeListener@422d77e0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()? 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity **.app.ListActivity has leaked IntentReceiver android.widget.PopupMenu$OrientationChangeListener@422d77e0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()? 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:826) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:621) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1072) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1059) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1053) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:357) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at android.widget.PopupMenu.<init>(PopupMenu.java:81) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at **.app.ListActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ListActivity.java:350) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2558) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:398) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:883) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$2.run(PhoneWindow.java:3008) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4491) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
10-21 20:55:28.461: E/ActivityThread(4526):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this particular problem by just creating the PopupMenu when its anchor button is first pressed. Since the leak only occurred when exiting the activity before showing the menu, I figured eliminating that state was a decent option.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    MenuItem login = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_login);
    final Button button = (Button) login.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.login);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View item) {
            if (profileMenu == null) {
                profileMenu = new PopupMenu(ListActivity.this, button);
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile_menu, profileMenu.getMenu());
                profileMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        // do something with item
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
            profileMenu.show();
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

There is one remaining edge case that causes the PopupMenu's window to be leaked.  I'll post that in a new question and link it here shortly.  I don't think I'll solve that one without reimplementing PopupMenu from scratch, though.